# Vue Threejs Frame Rate Slow on Larger JSON Files

Tags: javascript, vue.js, three.js

I am taking an old Three.js project that was in Angular 1.5 into Vue 2.6. The project visualizes Objects in JSON file format and I am getting ~12FPS on larger file that performed ~60FPS in Angular. This example uses `large_object` which is 3.6mb and `small_object` which is 84kb for file comparison.

I am in three.js 85 due to the use of the old THREE.json loader being deprecated in newer versions. Would this be the issue - and a possible solution be re-exporting these models in the newer standard? The question would still remain as to why the frame-rate would be so much lower in Vue as compared to Angular when loading the exact same files.

App.js

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="modelView"></div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import Stats from "stats.js";
import * as THREE from 'three'
const OrbitControls = require('three-orbit-controls')(THREE)

export default {
  data(){
    return {
      camera: null,
      scene: new THREE.Scene(),
      renderer: null,
      controls: null, 
      loader: new THREE.ObjectLoader(),
      context: null,
      animationFrameID: null,
      stats: null
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    this.init()
    this.loader.load("./large_object.json", this.loadModel,this.onProgress, this.onError)
    this.animate();
  },
  methods:{
    init: function(){
      this.container = document.getElementById('modelView')

      this.stats = new Stats();
      this.stats.showPanel( 0 ); // 0: fps, 1: ms, 2: mb, 3+: custom
      document.body.appendChild( this.stats.dom );

      var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xe8ecff, 1.4)
      ambient.name = 'ambientLight'
      this.scene.add(ambient)
      // set up renderer
      this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true })
      this.renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio)
      this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight )
      // this.renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true
      // this.renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap
      this.scene.background = new THREE.Color('rgb(255, 255, 255)')
      this.scene.fog = new THREE.Fog(0x1a2050, 10000, 10000)

      this.container.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement)

      // set up camera and controls
      this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 20, 15000)
      this.camera.position.set(300, 400, 900)

      this.controls = new OrbitControls(this.camera, this.renderer.domElement)
      this.controls.update()
    },
    animate: function () {
      this.animationFrameID = requestAnimationFrame(this.animate)
      this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera)
      this.stats.update()
    },
    loadModel: function(obj){
      this.scene.add(obj)
    },
    // callback function for loadlayers function while parsing json
    onProgress: function (xhr) {
      console.log( (xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded' );
    },
    // callback function for loadlayers function while parsing json
    onError: function (err) {
      console.error('An error happened')
    },
  }
}
</script>
<style lang="scss">
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
}
#modelView{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I would take a look on how many times your Vue methods are executed in 
 comparison to the Angular.js ones (`console.log`). As a side note: don't use `document.getElementById()`. You cannot reuse that component on the same page, because an element's ID must be unique within the document. Use `<div ref="modelView"></div>` and `this.$refs.modelView`.

Comment: I would suggest using the vue dev tools, they have a performance display where you can see what exactly is happening behind the scenes and how it's affecting your FPS

Comment: Also, why are you tracking `loader` and `scene` in data? wouldn't it be performant to have them as external variables below the imports rather than have them change tracked. This could be the cause of the lag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By updating the geometry file from Geometry to Buffer Geometry increased the frame rate to 60FPS. It is also worth noting that this only solves one piece of this issue, as Vue makes each component reactive which can balloon the memory footprint on larger applications. Please reference this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58559139/why-is-my-three-js-animation-slower-in-vue-js/59993448#59993448) for additional information on making your components non-reactive.

Version

**Three.js r.112**

Comment: Just saw this, good on you for following up and not leaving it answer-less!