# Why is my Three.js animation slower in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, three.js

I'm trying to recreate this awesome wave simulation: https://codepen.io/cheekymonkey/pen/vMvYNV, in Vue.js. However the animation is really slow when I've recreated it in Vue.js

I've tried making all of the same functions as Vue.js methods and including the variables in the component's data property.

```
<template>
    <div id="container" style="width:100%; height:100vh;"></div>
</template>

<script>
import * as Three from 'three'
import SimplexNoise from'simplex-noise'

export default {
  name: 'ThreeTest',
  data() {
    return {
      camera: Three.PerspectiveCamera,
      scene: Three.Scene,
      renderer: Three.WebGLRenderer,
      mesh: Three.Mesh,
      noise: SimplexNoise,
      geometry: null,
      factor: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    init: function() {
      this.createScene();
      this.createCamera();
      this.createShape();
      this.addSpotlight('#fdffab');
      this.addAmbientLight();
      this.animate();
      window.addEventListener('resize', this.onResize())

    },
    onResize: function() {
      let container = document.getElementById('container');
      this.renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight);
      this.camera.aspect = container.clientWidth / container.clientHeight;
      this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    },
    createScene: function() {
      this.scene = new Three.Scene();
      this.renderer = new Three.WebGLRenderer({
        antialias: true,
        alpha: true
      });
      let container = document.getElementById('container');
      this.renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight);
      this.renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
      this.renderer.setClearColor(new Three.Color('#fff'));
      //this.render.shadowMap.type = Three.PCFSoftShadowMap;
      this.noise = new SimplexNoise()
      container.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);
    },
    createCamera: function() {
      this.camera = new Three.PerspectiveCamera(20, container.clientWidth/container.clientHeight, 1, 1000);
      this.camera.position.set(0, 0, 20);
    },
    createShape: function() {
      const seg = 100
      this.geometry = new Three.PlaneGeometry(5, 8, seg, seg)
      const material = new Three.MeshPhysicalMaterial({
        color: '#da0463',
        metalness: 0.6,
        emissive: '#000',
        side: Three.DoubleSide,
        wireframe: true
      })
      this.mesh = new Three.Mesh(this.geometry, material)
      this.mesh.receiveShadow = true
      this.mesh.castShadow = true
      this.mesh.position.set(0, 0, 0)
      this.mesh.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 3
      this.mesh.rotation.z = -Math.PI / 4
      this.scene.add(this.mesh)
    },
    addSpotlight: function(color) {
      const light = new Three.SpotLight(color, 2, 1000)
      light.position.set(0, 0, 30)
      this.scene.add(light)
    },
    addAmbientLight: function() {
      const light = new Three.AmbientLight('#fff', 0.5)
      this.scene.add(light)
    },
    addjustVertices: function() {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.geometry.vertices.length; i++) {
        const vertex = this.geometry.vertices[i]
        const x = vertex.x / 4
        const y = vertex.y / 6
        vertex.z = this.noise.noise2D(x, y + this.factor)
      }
      this.factor += 0.007
      this.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true
      this.geometry.computeVertexNormals()
    },
    animate: function() {
        requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
        this.addjustVertices();
        this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
      this.init();
  }
}
</script>
```

It works, as in the wave animates like it should, but it's much slower. Not sure if this is due to Vue.js or just how I've set it up. Any advice much appreciated!

Comment: Can you clearly notice the difference when you run them next to each other? Also, do you see a difference in Vue development mode and build mode?

Comment: @ThomasvanBroekhoven I'm experiencing this kind of thing, but in dev mode only. Do you encountered any of this and have solution already?

Answer (score 2):

This is occurring because Vue under the hood makes each component attached to the instance reactive. [Reactivity in Depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html). Open up the dev tools and look at your memory footprint, when I ran your snippet on my machine it is ~300mb as opposed to the codepen example which is ~20mb.

When you `console.log(this.scene)` what you see are the getters/setters that allow Vue to track objects.

[image: console output of this.scene]

The below snippet pulls the three.js objects out of the Vue data object and attaches them to a [vue-static](https://github.com/samuelantonioli/vue-static) object. This plugin allows you to set certain variables as non-reactive.

```
<template>
    <div id="container" style="width:100%; height:100vh;"></div>
</template>

<script>
import * as Three from 'three'
import SimplexNoise from'simplex-noise'

export default {
  name: 'ThreeTest',
  static(){
    return {
      scene: new Three.Scene(),
      camera: null,
      renderer: Three.WebGLRenderer,
      mesh: new Three.Mesh,
      noise: SimplexNoise,
      factor:0
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.init();
  },
  methods: {
    init: function() {
      this.createScene();
      this.createCamera();
      this.createShape();
      this.addSpotlight('#fdffab');
      this.addAmbientLight();
      this.animate();
      window.addEventListener('resize', this.onResize())
    },
    onResize: function() {
      let container = document.getElementById('container');
      this.renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight);
      this.camera.aspect = container.clientWidth / container.clientHeight;
      this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    },
    createScene: function() {
      
      console.log("TCL: this.$options.bigHairyHorseNuts ",this.bigHairyHorseNuts)

      this.renderer = new Three.WebGLRenderer({
        antialias: true,
        alpha: true
      });
      let container = document.getElementById('container');
      this.renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight);
      this.renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
      this.renderer.setClearColor(new Three.Color('#fff'));
      //this.render.shadowMap.type = Three.PCFSoftShadowMap;
      this.noise = new SimplexNoise()
      container.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);
    },
    createCamera: function() {
      this.camera = new Three.PerspectiveCamera(20, container.clientWidth/container.clientHeight, 1, 1000);
      this.camera.position.set(0, 0, 20);
    },
    createShape: function() {
      const seg = 100
      this.geometry = new Three.PlaneGeometry(5, 8, seg, seg)
      const material = new Three.MeshPhysicalMaterial({
        color: '#da0463',
        metalness: 0.6,
        emissive: '#000',
        side: Three.DoubleSide,
        wireframe: true
      })
      this.mesh = new Three.Mesh(this.geometry, material)
      this.mesh.receiveShadow = true
      this.mesh.castShadow = true
      this.mesh.position.set(0, 0, 0)
      this.mesh.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 3
      this.mesh.rotation.z = -Math.PI / 4
      this.scene.add(this.mesh)
    },
    addSpotlight: function(color) {
      const light = new Three.SpotLight(color, 2, 1000)
      light.position.set(0, 0, 30)
      this.scene.add(light)
    },
    addAmbientLight: function() {
      const light = new Three.AmbientLight('#fff', 0.5)
      this.scene.add(light)
    },
    addjustVertices: function() {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.geometry.vertices.length; i++) {
        const vertex = this.geometry.vertices[i]
        const x = vertex.x / 4
        const y = vertex.y / 6
        vertex.z = this.noise.noise2D(x, y + this.factor)
      }
      this.factor += 0.007
      this.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true
      this.geometry.computeVertexNormals()
    },
    animate: function() {
        requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
        this.addjustVertices();
        this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: or just move this.scene = new Three.Scene() in the mounted lifecycle

Comment: If you move the `this.scene` to mounted, it is not performant as the Vue instance has made that object reactive ballooning the file size. Would you be able to provide an example of your solution achieving 60fps given the base case @wobsoriano?

Comment: Na, if you think you are correct then I don't have to provide a solution then. Additional knowledge for me :)